# OSX ffmpeg compilation

Tags: ffmpeg

In my OSX project I'm using `ffmpeg` lib. When I try build project with Release configuration XCode can't link with `ffmpeg` library:

> libavformat.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

But I can't compile `ffmpeg` for i386. I have tried many variants of configuration flags (./configure --arch=i386 etc. ), but without success.

Comment: Why do you need ffmpeg in i386 mode? In fact that any macs that was builded after 2007 year supports x64. Also before building for concrete arch you should be sure that dependence libraries also supports i386. You can use MacPorts for building and installing ffmpeg in universal mode. [Is MacPorts Universal?](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/FAQ#universal)